# вызов картинки через get_option

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет! На сайте Wordpress пытаюсь отобразить во фронтенде картинку, которую загружаю через собственную настройку в родном кастомайзере. Работает только такой вариант:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod('logo'); ?>"/>
```

Но мне бы хотелось через get_option, который, говорят, быстрее работает.
Но вот так:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_option('logo'); ?>"/>
```

не получается. Пишет `<img src (unknown)>`. Кто дурак? Найти в документации не могу как вывести картинку. Может вообще нельзя?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очередные городские байки про скорость работы.

Функция `get_theme_mod()` использует `get_option()`. Вот ее код:

```
function get_theme_mods() {
    $theme_slug = get_option( 'stylesheet' );
    $mods = get_option( "theme_mods_$theme_slug" );
    if ( false === $mods ) {
        $theme_name = get_option( 'current_theme' );
        if ( false === $theme_name )
            $theme_name = wp_get_theme()->get('Name');
        $mods = get_option( "mods_$theme_name" ); // Deprecated location.
        if ( is_admin() && false !== $mods ) {
            update_option( "theme_mods_$theme_slug", $mods );
            delete_option( "mods_$theme_name" );
        }
    }
    return $mods;
}
```

Чтобы достать ваше значение через `get_option()`, придётся проделать то же самое.

Не слушайте вы этих "знатоков".